# Review ban because of an arguable answer

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

Just two minutes ago I got a review ban for **2 days**.

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you
>   should have reviewed differently, see:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13240388.
>
> Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing.

IMO, this answer should be a comment.

What you think?

Comment: "Too many" is not one...it's many.

Comment: ...and no. It's verbose and chatty (and yet unspecific) but the second line **is** an answer..

Comment: I made like *1500-2000* reviews in total and this is the second time I got this message. First one was my fault because I clicked the wrong button by mistake. Are you sure about "too many" part?

Comment: So you've been banned **before**? You don't get banned for getting ONE review wrong....and 2000 reviews in 2 months...WOW.

Comment: As I understand from your comments, reviewing is not a good thing and 2/2000 is not a good reviewing performance. And there is nothing wrong with this reviewed answer.

Comment: Then you understand wrong. Reviewing is a good thing, **correct** reviewing is better. You assume the number 2...I say it's more....and the answer is not *incorrect*..it's not how I would have answered but it is an answer...just not a good one.

Comment: If you see c++ and undefined behavior in one post you better skip. The behavior of the audit system is undefined in those cases ....

Comment: Also, considering you can only review 20 per day... have been on the site for 2 months, and need a certain amount of rep for reviews... I challenge your number of 1500-2000.... (+, IIRC from my own poor reviews days...... a ban is not just 2 wrong audits)

Comment: And this is why Docs rep should not give you main site privileges.

Comment: @EmreBolat you have had about 15 days of access to the Review queues, no? [Privileges Link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), at least some of them, unwinding your rep back to when you had 500

Comment: @Drew it has been two months or so.

Comment: Judging by Emre's user profile, it's ~1460 reviews, with a joining date of May 25th, which is 73 days. Basically, 20 reviews every single day since joining.

Comment: @JonSkeet That assumes he has enough rep to review on the day he joined.  I looks like it would have been a few weeks before he had enough rep to review even the queues with the lowest requirements.

Comment: @Servy: True. First review was on June 14th, suggesting 1460 reviews in 52 days, so 28 per day. Sounds like the limit isn't 20 per day then...

Comment: @JonSkeet You're assuming all of the reviews are from one queue.  The review limits are per queue.

Comment: @Servy: Ah, that would explain it, yes.

Answer (score 32):

The question was

> Is it bad to declare a C-style string without const? If so, why?

And the answer was

> It's bad. It's very bad. To the point this isn't possible to do anymore in C++11.
>
> Modifying the memory of a string literal is undefined behaviour.

That's an answer to the question asked. It's not a comment. Comments are for clarification of questions and answers.

Just because an answer is short does not make it a comment.